# Share an android notification to whatsapp/email/other 3rd party apps

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I would like to give my users the option of sharing the text of a notification that my app produces to other apps.

Below is the code that I have attempted, but does not result in any success. It does open the "share via" screen when I click the share button on the notification, but the text that is shared that appears from "Intent.EXTRA_TEXT" makes no sense. If I do a Log check on what "sShare" is, then it shows me the correct string.

Please assist in anyway that you can.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sShare);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

            PendingIntent sendPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent, 0);

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
            mBuilder.setContentText(sOther);
            mBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.share, "Share", sendPendingIntent);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent sendPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```